# Doc to PDF with PHP + Openoffice

Tags: php, pdf, openoffice.org

I am trying to follow a tutorial on converting doc to pdf using openoffice. I have the following code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0); 
function MakePropertyValue($name, $value,$osm){ 
   $oStruct = $osm->Bridge_GetStruct("com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue"); 
   $oStruct->Name = $name; 
   $oStruct->Value = $value; 
   return $oStruct; 
} 
function word2pdf($doc_url, $output_url){ 
   // Invoke the OpenOffice.org service manager 
   $osm = new COM("com.sun.star.ServiceManager") or die ("Please be sure that OpenOffice.org is installed.\n"); 
   // Set the application to remain hidden to avoid flashing the document onscreen 
   $args = array(MakePropertyValue("Hidden",true,$osm)); 
   // Launch the desktop 
   $top = $osm->createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop"); 
   // Load the .doc file, and pass in the "Hidden" property from above 
   $oWriterDoc = $top->loadComponentFromURL($doc_url,"_blank", 0, $args); 
   // Set up the arguments for the PDF output 
   $export_args = array(MakePropertyValue("FilterName","writer_pdf_Export",$osm)); 
   // Write out the PDF 
   $oWriterDoc->storeToURL($output_url,$export_args); 
   $oWriterDoc->close(true); 
} 
$output_dir = './'; 
$doc_file = './test.docx'; 
$pdf_file = 'DpmR5Reqv1.20.pdf'; 
$output_file = $output_dir . $pdf_file; 
$doc_file = 'file:///' . $doc_file; 
$output_file = 'file:///' . $output_file; 
word2pdf($doc_file,$output_file); 
?>
```

I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `com.sun.star.ServiceManager' in C:\wamp\www\Projects\doc_to_pdf\index.php on line 11
( ! ) com_exception: Failed to create COM object `com.sun.star.ServiceManager': Invalid syntax in C:\wamp\www\Projects\doc_to_pdf\index.php on line 11
```

Ive tried to what this tutorial suggests: http://puno.ayun.web.id/2009/08/php-ooo-in-microsoft-windows-environment/ But no luck. Any idea what I can do? I am running this under wamp and it will be ran under wamp in production.

Comment: Oh god, surely there is an easier way to convert a .doc to a PDF than with OpenOffice. Look up AntiWord. you can convert from doc to PDF very simply from the command line

Comment: The error you describe appears to indicate that the openoffice com object is not properly installed or perhaps not registered with the system. I could not find a direct link to help rectify this problem, but you would be looking for a way to register the component. Perhaps it is an optional item in the openoffice install which must be manually selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have OpenOffice setup to run as a service on that machine. To simply convert an odt to a pdf you can use pyodconverter. They also explain how to setup the local OpenOffice service:
http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter

I'm using this technique in a script I wrote and have an article for here:
http://codeuniversity.com/scripts/scr1

Answer (score 0):

Please install Open Office in your Directory.  OpenOffice setup to run as a service on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

it is much easier to use headless libreoffice and a php wrapper class like https://github.com/ncjoes/office-converter.
of course you have to install libreoffice and you must have full control of your webserver.