# How to convert documents from .doc to text

Tags: php, linux, ms-word

I have been pondering writing this question for quite some time.

I work for a small-sized news corporation in Vietnam.

The server I have is running for documents is the latest version of Ubuntu (with PHP/Apache obviously), which means that formats such as .doc and .docx will not be  able to be opened natively, as far as I know.

However, when reporters upload documents, half the time they do it in some sort of Microsoft format. This means my Linux machine cannot open and pick out keywords, which is extremely frustrating to me; this is because things like `pdf2txt.py` do not work.

Is a way to get around this problem, without inconveniencing the reporters too much? I understand that since I am running a Linux server, I may have to run some sort of third-party application to do the work for me, which could work in the short run, but it could pose some security risks.

**Summary**: How can I have a Linux server automatically convert any format such as .doc and .docx to PDF for further manipulation?

Comment: Use OpenOffice/LibreOffice. It does a pretty good job opening MSOffice files.

Comment: Microsoft Word docx files are XML, so you should be able to parse out their metadata fairly easily.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doc to PDF with PHP + Openoffice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652038/doc-to-pdf-with-php-openoffice) -- It's easier with LibreOffice however, as it provides a headless commandline switch.

Comment: @mario I am also interested in possible third-party (altnerate server) solutions, to provide as much fidelity to the original document as possible.

Comment: Then also check [reading docx (Office Open XML) in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501623/reading-docx-office-open-xml-in-php)

Comment: For the moment I am just going to disallow documents from being uploaded that are not PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For oldschool doc files, take a look at catdoc, and wv.

For an all around solution that can convert anything that OpenOffice can open to anything that OpenOffice can save, is [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, much happened recently and I was unable to check, instead I only implemented a block on non PDFs for the previous time being, now I am looking into this. :)